# Razor Syntax Equivalent

Tags: razor

The below line appears in one of my javascript files, what would be the syntax for it in Razor.

```
var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
```

Comment: You should be able to just use `var initialData = @new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);`, but I haven't begun using Razor for real yet, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Tomas: No; you need to wrap it in parentheses, to force the parser to read past the space.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah! Well, there's a reason I said that in a comment and not in an answer =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model))
```

The `Html.Raw` call is necessary to prevent it from being HTML-escaped.

Answer (score 7):

For a more succinct feel, you can use the Web Pages Json helper's Encode method:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the serialized JavaScript to properly support `DateTime`, use the serializer from [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070083/1259510), even Microsoft uses this for serialization with MVC4.

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```