# JSON escaped characters in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, apostrophe

I'm sorry..  I know I'm going to get accused of asking a question which has already been asked many times before, but I have desperately searched, Googled and tried all kinds of suggestions, but nothing has worked for me.

I have a service returning some JSON data with an apostrophe in it.  So "`Mike's example record`" gets returned like this:

```
{
    "Results": [
    {
        "ID": 139,
        "Name": "Mike\u0027s example record",
        "CedentName": "Mikes Business Partner"
    }],
    "Success": "1"
}
```

What I want to know, is how to get jqGrid to convert this `\u0027` code back into an apostrophe.

[image]

I know, I know, this must be an obvious setting, but I have searched, Googled, tried adding 
functions to the jqGrid `datatype` attribute, and so on, but nothing has worked.

Here's the code I use to load the JSON data, and populate the jqGrid:

```
$("#tblCustomers").jqGrid({
                 url: '/JSON/GetCustomers.aspx',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 datatype: "json",
                 viewrecords: true,
                 loadonce: true,
                 jsonReader: {
                    root: "Results",   //arry containing actual data 
                    id: "ID",          //index of the column with the PK in it 
                    repeatitems: false
                 },
                 . . .
                 . . .
                 autoencode: true,
                 caption: ""
             });
```

Another question: out of interest, I added another record with speechmarks in it.

Bizarrely, the `JavaScriptSerializer()` function produced invalid JSON, and then, nothing got displayed in the jqGrid !!

```
string JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listOfRecords).ToString();
```

produced the following *invalid* JSON string.

Notice how it *hasn't* encoded the speechmark into `\u0022` :

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "ID": 140,
            "Name": "Mikes \\"Speechmark test\\" RP",
            "CedentName": "Mikes Cedent"
        },
```

I can't be the only person noticing this quirk, can I...?

**A little while later..**

After reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070083/391605) and seeing the way `JavaScriptSerializer()` formats dates, using Microsoft's own unsupported format:

```
StartDate: "\/Date(1401573600000)\/",
```

..I realised that `JavaScriptSerializer()` is pretty nasty, and replaced it with [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Strangely, this class *also* fails miserably when it comes to serializing values containing speechmarks, and happily creates invalid JSON strings (it has the same incorrect format as shown above, with a speechmark left in the middle of the field value).

However, it does, at least leave apostrophes alone, so I can view my data in jqGrid without the need for formatters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest thing I've found to an answer.

You can apply a formatter to each cell in the grid, to force it to parse the JSON value, which will convert `\u0027` escape codes back into apostrophes.

```
function formatCell(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
    return JSON.parse("\"" + cellValue + "\"");
}
```

then add this formatter to *each column* in your jqGrid:

```
$("#tblCustomers").jqGrid({
                 url: '/JSON/GetCustomers.aspx',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 datatype: "json",
                 colModel: [
                     { name: "ID", width: 70, align: "center", formatter: formatCell },
                     { name: "Name", search: true, width: 290, formatter: formatCell },
                     { name: "CedentName", search: true, width: 290, formatter: formatCell }
                 ],
                 . . .
```

This does work, and I finally get to see the apostrophe in my jqGrid:

[image]

But there must be a cleaner way of doing this...?