# Unexpected DateTime output when receiving JSON in .NET webservice

Tags: json, vb.net, datetime, .net-3.5, json.net

I have a piece of code that is giving me an unexpected output when taking a json date parameter. (this has been noticed as the software is being used in a different timezone to the one it was created in)

the html is a basic jquery datepicker field, so nothing wrong with that. I am just trying to match the date selected with a date in the database.

the JSON datetime that goes into the WebMethod `FindDuplicates` is in the correct format

`2015-09-17T00:00:00.000Z`

the javascript that calls the webservice is simply:

```
findDuplicates : function(options, success, error) {
    if(''+options.name == '' && ''+options.dateToCompare == '') {
        success&&success([], 'success', null);
        return;
    }
    return $software.__call_ajaxws('/webservices/FindDuplicates', { nameToMatch: options.name || null, dateToCompare: options.dateToCompare }, null, success || void (0), error || void (0), { elContent: 'Searching for duplicate records' });
}
```

in this (the none working) code, the variable `dateToCompare`

```
<WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json), PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated:=True)> _
Public Function FindDuplicates(ByVal nameToMatch As String, ByVal dateToCompare As Nullable(Of DateTime))
    Dim someValue as String = "Foo"
```

at the point `Dim someValue as String = "Foo"` the value of `dateToCompare` has become `2015-09-17 09:00:00`

whereas if I change the type of `dateToCompare` to a string it shows correctly as `2015-09-17 00:00:00`

for some reason i cant work out, when casting/converting the parameter to a DateTime it decides to add the timezone of the server to the date, thereby sending an incorrect date to the comparison function meaning that a DB stored value of `2015-09-17 00:00:00` wont ever compare because it is being compared with `2015-09-17 09:00:00`

is there someway I can stop the conversion process of string to datetime adding the timezone of the server?

Comment: @varocarbas at the first line within the function FindDuplicates dateToCompare has already had it's timezone added to it when it became cast as a type DateTime

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET AJAX in .NET 3.5, I think the JSON serializer being used automatically is `JavaScriptSerializer`, not Json.NET.  Source: http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/json-serializers-in-aspnet-and-other.html.  How are you configuring / setting up your JSON serializer?

Comment: You should specify the conditions of the corresponding conversion to `DateTime` (via serialiser, as suggested by dbc, or by any other means). I deleted my previous comments because of not being completely sure about its actual applicability here. In any case the provided code (i.e., just including `dateToCompare As Nullable(Of DateTime)` and the input string) is not enough to understand the problem. A conversion from string to `DateTime` has to be performed (in a really bad scenario, it might be performed implicitely via `Option Strict Off`) and this part should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you appear to be using ASP.NET AJAX in .NET 3.5, and this actually uses `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize method arguments, according to the article [*Json serializers in ASP.NET and other*](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/json-serializers-in-aspnet-and-other.html).  Thus your `DateTime` is not being deserialized for you by Json.NET, it's being deserialized for you by `JavaScriptSerializer`

And it appears that `JavaScriptSerializer` has bugs with correctly deserializing timezones of `DateTime` structs, according to [JavaScriptSerializer UTC DateTime issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069460/javascriptserializer-utc-datetime-issues).  That question further suggests a workaround: declare your argument as a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and then extract the time with [`UtcDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
Public Function FindDuplicates(ByVal nameToMatch As String, ByVal dateToCompare As Nullable(Of DateTimeOffset))
    Dim actualDateToCompare as Nullable(Of DateTime)
    if dateToCompare Is Nothing Then
        actualDateToCompare = Nothing
    else
        actualDateToCompare = dateToCompare.Value.UtcDateTime
    End If
```

A simple test case (in c#) seems to show that this fixes the problem:

```
        var jsonString = @"""2015-09-17T00:00:00.000Z""";

        var ok1 = (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(jsonString) == new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTimeOffset>(jsonString).UtcDateTime);
        Debug.Assert(ok1); // No assert

        var ok2 = (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(jsonString) == new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTime>(jsonString));
        Debug.Assert(ok2); // Assert FAILS
```